# Wifi Issue with Atheros AR956x

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I am using the laptop for 2 years. It had no problems. Now, it automatically disconnects from my Access Point windows gives the error - Can't connect to this network. Sometimes, even the router login page does not load even sitting next to router. this happens every 15 minutes. I have tried resetting wireless adapter, re-enabling it, updating drivers. After saying that - Can't connect to network, Wifi name disappears. Other devices are working fine.

Comment: Hello. Have you checked for malware? Sometimes this can be the issue.  Does the WIFI signal come back with low signal if you are right next to the wifi router? (this would indicate a bad antenna)

Comment: Update the BIOS and the Wireless Driver to see if the driver is at fault. If this fails, try a USB Wireless card and see if that maintains a connection.

Comment: no bios update for lenovo.

Comment: The wireless adapter may be failing. If it has ethernet, connect that way and see if you have the same symptoms.

Comment: @Moab you were right. I forgot to update this post. I bought a new wireless adapter, and now everything works fine. You can post this as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wireless adapter may be failing.

If it has ethernet, connect that way and see if you have the same symptoms.

Comment: It worked! ```+1```:)